# Teamcity: number of busy agents at any time

Tags: teamcity

I'm new to team city

is there a way thru the api to know the number of busy agents at a given time

I know I can do this to get the list of agents

```
teamcityhost/app/rest/agents/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TeamCity can only run a single job per agent they are a 1:1 mapping. You can get a list of the running builds using a build locator like this. The default count limit is 100, so if you have more than 100 agents you'll want to include something big:

```
/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=running:true&count=200
```

You'll get back something like this with a count on the root element:

```
<builds count="1" nextHref="...">
  <build id="10458" ... />
</builds>
```

If you are using TeamCity 8.1, JetBrains have added an endpoint for queue builds, however the instance I've got here is only 8.0 so I could test it for you. If you use this make sure you filter it to just running builds to exclude those that are actually queued waiting for an agent.
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-QueuedBuilds